# MVC5 Form won't post; submit button does nothing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, submit

We are in the process of redesigning the UI in our ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. We're moving to the bootstrap framework, and finally making the switch from aspx views to razor views.

I have this form -

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Dashboard", "Reports")) {
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Select date ranges & display currency</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="reportRequest_FromDate" class="control-label">Month:</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.reportRequest.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="reportRequest_CompareFromDate" class="control-label">Compare:</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.reportRequest.CompareFromDate, new { @class = "form-control"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Currency:</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(t => t.reportRequest.Currency,Html.GetBaseCurrency(), new { @class = "form-control"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></span> Display Report</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here I select a two months (a default month, and another month for comparison), and a currency.

Clicking on the Submit button does absolutely nothing. I have tried changing it to a simple -

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

to see if this was my issue, but the behaviour was the same.

This strikes me as something simple, but after web searching I've come up blank. I'm probably not using the right terms to search. Can anyone see if there's anything I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have a method Dashboard in ReportsController?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes. Of Course. Found the issue. CompareFromDate is an optional field. The new UI was not allowing me to submit if I left this textbox blank. I need to do a bit of digging on that issue, but it was preventing me from submitting in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to post data using this, try this overloaded version of BeginForm method

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Dashboard", "Reports",FormMethod.Post,null))
```

Hope will help.

Comment: using `@Html.BeginForm (String, String)` uses the post method.

Comment: unless the method doesn't exist or parameters don't match or the controller and action name are the wrong way round!

Comment: no, this could not be the reason, b'coz there must be an exception in this case .

Comment: possibly, unless theres exception handling going on somewhere which doesn't surface. This question needs more detail.

Comment: @AnupamSingh thanks for your help - Found the issue. CompareFromDate is an optional field. The new UI was not allowing me to submit if I left this textbox blank. I need to do a bit of digging on that issue, but it was preventing me from submitting in this case.